# How to work out the time complexity in terms of the number of operations

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

so I was wondering how would I work out the time complexity (*T(n)*) of a piece of code, for example, the one below, in terms of the number of operations.

```
for( int i = n; i > 0; i /= 2 ) {
    for( int j = 1; j < n; j *= 2 ) {
        for( int k = 0; k < n; k += 2 ) {
            ... // constant number of operations
        }
    }
}
```

I'm sure its simple but this concept wasn't taught very well by my lecturer and I really want to know how to work out the time complexity!

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why don't you count the number of operations in the inner loop, test with different values of n, and then try to explain the data you observe? That's called the empirical approach. :)

Answer (score 3):

To approach this, one method is to breakdown the complexity of your three loops individually.

A key observation we can make is that:

**(P): The number of steps in each of the loop does not depend on the value of the "index" of its parent loop.**

Let's call

- `f(n)` the number of operations aggregated in the outer loop (1)
- `g(n)` in the intermediate inner loop (2)
- `h(n)` in the most inner loop (3).

  ```
  for( int i = n; i > 0; i /= 2 ) {            // (1): f(n)
      for( int j = 1; j < n; j *= 2 ) {        // (2): g(n)
          for( int k = 0; k < n; k += 2 ) {    // (3): h(n)
             // constant number of operations  // => (P)
          }
      }
  }
  ```

### Loop (1)

**Number of steps**
`i` gets the values `n`, `n/2`, `n/4`, ... etc. until it reaches `n/2^k` where `2^k` is greater than `n` (`2^k > n`), such that `n/2^k = 0`, at which point you exit the loop.

Another way to say it is that you have step 1 (`i = n`), step 2 (`i = n/2`), step 3 (`i = n/4`), ... step `k - 1` (`i = n/2^(k-1)`), then you exit the loop. These are `k` steps.

Now what is the value of `k`?  Observe that `n - 1 <= 2^k < n <=> log2(n - 1) <= k < log2(n) <= INT(log2(n - 1)) <= k <= INT(log2(n))`. This makes `k = INT(log2(n))` or loosely speaking `k = log2(n)`.

**Cost of each step**
*Now how many operations do you have for each individual step?*

At step `i`, it is `g(i) = g(n)` according to the notations we chose and the property **(P)**.

### Loop (2)

**Number of steps**
You have step (1) (`j = 1`), step (2) (`j = 2`), step (3) (`j = 4`), etc. until you reach step (p) (`j = 2^p`) where `p` is defined as the smallest integer such that `2^p > n`, or loosely speaking `log2(n)`.

**Cost of each step**
The cost of step `j` is `h(j) = h(n)` according to the notations we chose and the property **(P)**.

### Loop (3)

**Number of steps**
Again, let's count the steps: (1):`k = 0`, (1):`k = 2`, (2):`k = 4`, ..., `k = n - 1 or k = n - 2`. This amounts to `n / 2` steps.

**Cost of each step**
Because of **(P)**, it is constant. Let's call this constant `K`.

### All loops altogether

The number of aggregated operations is

```
T(n) = f(n) = sum(i = 0, i < log2(n), g(i))
            = sum(i = 0, i < log2(n), g(n))
            = log2(n).g(n)
            = log2(n).sum(j = 0, j < log2(n), h(j))
            = log2(n).log2(n).h(n)
            = log2(n).log2(n).(n/2).K
```

So `T(n) = (K/2).(log2(n))^2.n`

Comment: thank you! but I was wondering how did (n/2).K become K/2? :)

Comment: `n` is actually at the end of the expression - it could also be written `T(n) = (K/2).n.(log2(n))^2`

Answer (score -1):

Write a method, add a counter, return the result:

```
int nIterator (int n) {
    int counter = 0;
    for( int i = n; i > 0; i /= 2 ) {
        for( int j = 1; j < n; j *= 2 ) {
            for( int k = 0; k < n; k += 2 ) {
                ++counter;
            }
        }
    }
    return counter;
}
```

Protocol for fast increasing N and document in a readable manner the results:

```
int old = 0;
for (int i = 0, j=1; i < 18; ++i, j*=2) {
    int res = nIterator (j);
    double quote = (old == 0) ? 0.0 : (res*1.0)/old;
    System.out.printf ("%6d %10d %3f\n", j, res, quote);    
    old=res;
}
```

Result:

```
     1          0 0,000000
     2          2 0,000000
     4         12 6,000000
     8         48 4,000000
    16        160 3,333333
    32        480 3,000000
    64       1344 2,800000
   128       3584 2,666667
   256       9216 2,571429
   512      23040 2,500000
  1024      56320 2,444444
  2048     135168 2,400000
  4096     319488 2,363636
  8192     745472 2,333333
 16384    1720320 2,307692
 32768    3932160 2,285714
 65536    8912896 2,266667
131072   20054016 2,250000
```

So n is increasing by factor 2, the counter increases in the beginning with more than 2², but then decreases rapidly towards something, not much higher than 2. This should help you find the way.