# Time complexity for two nested for loops

Tags: time, time-complexity, complexity-theory

This question is for revision from a past test paper just needed advice if I on the right track.

Work out the time complexity `T(n)` of the following piece of code in terms of number of operations for a given `integer n`:

```
for ( int k = n; k >0; k /= 3 ) {
  for ( int i = 0; i < n; i += 2 ) {
     // constant number C of elementary operations
  }
  for ( int j = 2; j < n; j = (j*j)) {
      // constant number C of elementary operations
  }
}
```

So I thought the outer loop would be `O(logn)`, the first inner loop would be `O(n)` and the second inner loop would be `O(logn)`. Just wanted to know if I had a rough idea and how to move forward from here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was recently a question somewhat similar few days ago for which I provided a step-by-step description of complexity analysis: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49093954/926701

- The outer loop is indeed `O(log3(n))`
- The first inner loop is indeed `O(n)`
- The second inner loop is `O(log2(log2(n)))`

Informally, for the second loop, with `j(k)` the sequence of values taken by the index `j` of the `for` loop, we can write:

```
j(1) = 2, j(2) = j(1)^2 = 4, j(3) = j(2)^2 = 16, ..., j(k) = j(k-1)^2 >= n 
=> j(k) = j(k-1)^2 = j(k-2)^4 = ... = j(1)^(2^k) = 2^(2^k)
=> k = log2(log2(n))
```

Since the number of operations in the inner loops is **independent** from that of the outer loop, we can multiply the complexity:

```
T(n) = O(log3(n) * (n + log2(log2(n))))
     = O(n.log3(n))
```

because `log2(log2(n)) << n` as `n -> +Inf`.

Comment: Why is the second loop `n^(1/log2(log2(n))))` instead of simply `log2(log2(n))`?

Comment: Thank you for pointing the mistake out, I corrected the post.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't quite get it, why do you go j(2) = j(1) ^ 2 = 4 ? how'd the 2 go into 1 ?

Comment: @ross.c Not sure I understand your question, but `j(1)` is the first value assigned to `j` in the loop, so `2`, and the next is `j(1) = 2 * 2 = 4`. Is this what you wanted to clarify?

Comment: @AlexandreDupriez yes thats better sorry I thought for some reason it was (1) ^ 2 as in 1 * 1 so was getting confused ! thanks for the help :)